# Does google have some light weight MVC framework they use and released?

Tags: java, web-frameworks

Is there a light weight MVC framework that google released and that they use internally?

I know they released google Guice, but that's just an dependancy injectory component from what I gather.

I thought I read somewhere they have a web application framework also.

Comment: It is imho spelled `Google Guice` http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/, but spoken `juice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a lot of Open Source products, but as a web framework the [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is probably what you are looking for:

> Google Web Toolkit (GWT) is a development toolkit for building and
>   optimizing complex browser-based applications. GWT is used by many
>   products at Google, including Google AdWords and Orkut. It's open
>   source, completely free, and used by thousands of developers around
>   the world.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of the [Google Web Toolkit.](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)

Comment: He did say "lightweight", though :)

Comment: Lol, I thought the same thing, but "lightweight" and "mvc framework" is a pretty tough combination and gwt is the only web framework google has published afaik.  Maybe Stripes would qualify as a "lightweight mvc framework"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked your question a new project has been written and released [Lime-MVC](http://code.google.com/p/lime-mvc/) that attempts to replicate Springs MVC but using Guice.

Answer (score 0):

The closest product to a MVC framework that Google has is GWT (Google Web Toolkit).
It isn't a complete MVC framework though. Using GWT you can write code in Java that is compiled to Javascript and run in the browser. It provides a good basis for View and Controller components. Your Model code runs on the server and is called via AJAX.

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There was a thing called [GoogleSiteBricks](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/). It was an MVC based on guice, but I don't think it is currently being maintained.

It has a github link now